# Arduino keep button state

Tags: button, arduino, arduino-uno

How can I turn a led on when I press on a button, then turn it off when I press again that button?

This is my code:

```
const int  buttonPin = 2;    
const int ledPin = 13;       

int buttonState = 0;         

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

Right now the led is on as long as I keep the button pressed...

I added the components and the code here:
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/dT2gVL0hJVf-swanky-krunk/editel?sharecode=s6M2OOyAQCZ8cePou13PBvkByEE-qr-baUN6UwUuckA=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code the onAndOff is boolean that has one of the two values (true, false) we put false in it if led is off we put true in it if led is on and we check if its true or false when we press the button if its false then turn the led on and put true in onAndOff otherwise turn off the led and put false in onAndOff

```
const int  buttonPin = 2;       
const int ledPin = 13; 

bool onAndOff = false;            

int buttonState = 0;  

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        if (onAndOff == false) {
            onAndOff = true;
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);     
        } else {
            onAndOff = false;
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```